# Uncode theme, create author page and author link under the blog

Tags: author, list-authors

On my company's website, there is a blog page which displays blogs of all team members. I want to create an author link below each blog which takes to the author individual page and this page displays their profile pic, bio and blogs they have written till date.
I am using Uncode theme. There is author module in it. I tried using it but it doesn't show different authors. It shows only current logged in user as author.

This is the url : https://www.copeace.com/blog

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

before making edits, please consider to create a child theme for your customization; https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

to show a link to the author's page (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/), put this code into the loop of the blog or post template file below the blog post code (please contact the theme's developer for help with where in what file of your theme exactly):

`<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author() ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>`

if not exists, create a template file **author.php** in your (child) theme (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#author-display), possibly starting with a copy of **archive.php** or **index.php** of your theme.

in that file, before the loop, add the code for the author bio:

`<?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>`

for the profile picture you could use the gravatar (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/)

Answer (score 0):

The author of the post (current logged-in user when writing it) will show as the Post Author. However, you can override that by editing the post (edit or quick edit - see screenshot below for quick edit).

Then, you could add a link at the bottom of each article to say something like:

```
See more posts by CoPeace (link to https://www.copeace.com/author/copeace-drafts or whatever).
```

[image: quick edit - author change]